# How can I randomly apply rotation and flip to arrays in a list of using python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of NumPy arrays, I want to apply `rot90` and `flip` function randomly on it. So that in the end, I have a list where some arrays are as it is, and some are modified (with that two fuctions).

I directly pass that list of arrays to `numpy.random.choice`, it gives me the following error `ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional`.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Better if you add input and expected output

Comment: arrays are too big(those are images). let me clarify a bit more. INPUT -: list of images. Output-: some images are the same as in Input, some should be modified (rot90 let's say). i want to apply `np.rot90` in that list randomly. is it clear? @DaniMesejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach it to create a population of functions and pick randomly, using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice), the one to apply to each image:

```
import random
import numpy as np

# for reproducibility
random.seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)

# toy data representing the list of images
images = [np.random.randint(255, size=(128, 128)) for _ in range(10)]

functions = [lambda x: x, np.rot90, np.flip]

# pick function at random at apply to image
res = [random.choice(functions)(image) for image in images]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just sample indices and apply to the array at the respecting index. So here is an example of the basic idea:

```
import numpy as np
# generate some random list of arrays
l = [np.random.randint(0,10,(4,4)) for _ in range(10)]

# sample indices and apply rotation and flip
indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(l)),int(len(l)/2),replace=False)
new_l = [np.flip(np.rot90(l[i])) if i in indices else l[i] for i in range(len(l))]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. it should work, but the size of the last output should be same as input. could you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you sample a list of indeces that needs to be modified?
In the following example, I have set:

- A list of functions which could be applied `transformations`
- If functions can be applied to the same only once (`apply_only_once=True`), or multiple applications are permitted (`apply_only_once=False`)
- Number of lines which must be modified is `n_lines_to_modify`. Clearly, if `apply_ony_once=True`, `n_lines_to_modify` must be less or equal to the number of rows in the array; note that, if `apply_only_once=False`,  `n_lines_to_modify` is not constrained, because multiple transformation can be applied to the same line (corner case: all the transformations applied to one line only!)
- `arrays` is just a test input

In code:

```
import random
import numpy as np

transformations = [lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x+2]
apply_only_once = True
n_lines_to_modify = 2
arrays = np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([3,4,5])])

if apply_only_once:
    to_be_modified = random.sample(range(len(arrays)), n_lines_to_modify)
else:
    to_be_modified = [random.choice(range(len(arrays))) for _ in range(n_lines_to_modify)]

for i in to_be_modified:
    arrays[i] = random.choice(transformations)(arrays[i])

print(arrays)
```